# Android ActionBar.Tab, Fragments, Sub-fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I currently have an Android app which has a few tabs (3 to be exact) in a navigation area. Clicking on each tab shows the fragment associated with the tab.

I want to be able to click on a button in the fragment that is showing and display a new fragment, which isn't part of any of the tabs. Basically, it's like a sub-screen for the previous page.

I was able to get the "sub-fragment" to display, and clicking on the back button will take me to the previous fragment which is what I want.

My problem is that when I click on another tab, the "sub-fragment" isn't going away. And if I click the back button, I get an IllegalStateException saying Fragment1 has already been added.

Here is some of the code which hopefully will help answer my question.

MainActivity:

```
public void OnTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
    {
        string tabTag = tab.Tag.ToString();

        Fragment f = FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag(tabTag);

        if (f != null)
        {
            ft.Show(f);
        }
        else
        {
            switch (tabTag)
            {
                case "Tab1":
                    f = new Fragment1();
                    break;
                case "Tab2":
                    f = new Fragment2();
                    break;
                case "Tab3":
                    f = new Fragment3();
                    break;
                default:
                    f = new NotImplementedTabFragment();
                    break;
            }

            ft.Add(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, f, tabTag);
         }
    }

    public void OnTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
    {
        string tabTag = tab.Tag.ToString();

        Fragment f = FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag(tabTag);

        if (f != null)
        {
            ft.Hide(f);
        }
    }
```

Fragment1:

```
public class Fragment1 : Fragment
{

    public override Android.Views.View OnCreateView(Android.Views.LayoutInflater inflater, Android.Views.ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Fragment1, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    protected void OnButtonClick(object sender, Android.Widget.AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var t = items[e.Position].ToString();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.Replace(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, new SubFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.AddToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

This is written in Xamarin (C#), but I do understand Java code, so any help/examples using Java are fine.

**Update:**

I realized that my MainActivityLayout.axml file was using a RelativeLayout instead of a FrameLayout this is why I had to use attach/detach instead of show/hide. Here is my new layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

It still isn't working as expected, but I don't get the exception anymore saying the fragment has already been added.

**Update 2:**

I've decided to scrap trying to use the OnTabSelected and OnTabUnselected and just use delegates since I'm using C#. The important code is this:

```
private void AddTab(Tab tab, Fragment fragment)
{
    Android.App.ActionBar.Tab droidTab = this.ActionBar.NewTab();
    droidTab.SetCustomView(new TabLayout(this));
    droidTab.SetTag(tab.ToString());

    droidTab.TabSelected += delegate(object sender, ActionBar.TabEventArgs e)
    {
        e.FragmentTransaction.Replace(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, fragment);
    };

    this.ActionBar.AddTab(droidTab);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is save a reference to SubFragment

```
Fragment subFrag;
protected void OnButtonClick(object sender, Android.Widget.AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var t = items[e.Position].ToString();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
    subFrag =  new SubFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.Replace(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, subFrag);
    fragmentTransaction.AddToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.Commit();
}
```

Then when Fragment1 is detatched, remove the subFrag

```
@Override public void onDetach() {
    if (subFrag != null) {
         FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
         fragmentTransaction.Remove(subFrag );
         fragmentTransaction.Commit();
    }
    super.onDetach();
}
```

Another (though a bit crude in my opinion) option could be to implement a `getSubFragment()` method in Fragment1 and do:

```
public void OnTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
{
    string tabTag = tab.Tag.ToString();

    Fragment f = FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag(tabTag);

    if (f instanceof Fragment1) {
        Fragment subFrag = ((Fragment1)f).getSubFragment();
        if (subFrag != null) {
            ft.Remove(f); 
        }
    }
    if (f != null)
    {
        ft.Hide(f);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've implemented what you said to do, but onDetach is never getting called.

According to Dianne Hackborn at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-platform/QlkLMsncDwg - "No, it's a little unfortunately naming.  onDetach() means detached from the activity.  Your fragment is still attached to the activity.  FragmentManager.detach() essentially puts it into the same state as when it is pushed on the fragment back stack."

Comment: Did you try and move it to another part of the lifecycle then, say, onDestroyView or onPause?

Comment: See my update. I was using a RelativeLayout instead of a FrameLayout to store the fragments in. The code isn't working the way I exactly want it to yet. It doesn't make the SubFragment go away when clicking on other tabs, but the content for the other fragment shows up. Kind of like a layering effect.

Comment: In java you would usually use getChildFragmentManager to get a FragmentManager to manage subfragments, just a thought. Will post another suggestion in a few moments.